# Object's prototype methods only returning function definitions, not executing.

Tags: javascript, oop

I was reviewing the prototypal way of creating and "instantiating" objects and I've run into a problem. When I put this code into the browser's console to test it out, if I enter:

```
nUser1.myAge()  // only the function definition is returned, doesn't actually execute.
```

I thought that perhaps I needed to have a return statement on the method, but that made no difference. Plus, in my previous (successful) practice attempts they didn't need a return statement to return the output of the respective methods.

I've looked through the code several times and compared it to my other examples and nothing is standing out. I feel like the problem is right under my nose, but I'm not seeing it.

```
function normUserCreator(name, age, employed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.employed = employed;
};

normUserCreator.prototype.myName = function() {
  console.log("My name is: " + this.name + ".")
};
normUserCreator.prototype.myAge = function() {
  console.log("My age is : " + this.myAge + ".")
};
normUserCreator.prototype.employed = function() {
  if (this.employed === true) {
    console.log("I am employed");
  } else if (this.employed === false) {
    console.log("I am not employed");
  }
};

var nUser1 = new normUserCreator('Kevin', 26, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in this line

```
console.log("My age is : " + this.myAge + ".")
```

It is basically calling itself.Replace it with `this.age`

Also you can replace `if (this.employed === true)` with `if (this.employed)` same for `else if` condition

```js
function normUserCreator(name, age, employed) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.employed = employed;
};

normUserCreator.prototype.myName = function() {
  console.log("My name is: " + this.name + ".")
};
normUserCreator.prototype.myAge = function() {
  console.log("My age is : " + this.age + ".")
};
normUserCreator.prototype.employed = function() {
  if (this.employed) {
    console.log("I am employed");
  } else if (!this.employed) {
    console.log("I am not employed");
  }
};

var nUser1 = new normUserCreator('Kevin', 26, false);
nUser1.myAge()
```

Comment: Probably want to make `console.log(nUser1.myAge())` just `nUser1.myAge()` so you don't get that `undefined`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something really subtle, just was struggling to find it. I also noticed that I was shadowing "employed" on my prototype, fixed that also.

Comment: here you could even reduce the `else if` to a mere `else`